# How do I create an employee using another variable as a name?

Tags: java

I have this code, I am using another file to house the Employee class but I would like to use firstName + lastName to be the name of the employee object. I want to do this so I can create Employee objects with this method and have unique names for each one

```
package com.aho;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public void createEmployee(String firstName, String lastName, int employeeCount){
        Employee firstName + lastName = new Employee();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter command: ");
        String command = input.nextLine();

        if(command.equals("Create new employee") || command.equals("create new employee")){
            System.out.println("\n" + "Input first name: ");
            String fName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("\n" + "Input last name: ");
            String lName = input.nextLine();
            createEmployee(fName,lName, employeeList.size());
        }else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is neither possible nor necessary in Java. Variables only hold references to objects.

Comment: What is the point of passing employeeList.size() to the createEmployee method?

Comment: Or, use a `HashMap` to store the "name" against the reference of the `Employee` object, or provide a better looking up mechanism to find an employee by name in the list

Answer (score 1):

As written, your code doesn't compile. You cannot use `+` to define variable names.

It appears that you want

```
Employee e = new Employee(fistName, lastName);
```

And maybe create a string `firstName + " " + lastName` within that class...

Then, when you add to the list, you need the method to actually return this instance, for example

```
employeeList.add(createEmployee(fName, lName));
```

Comment: but for E, will that make every employee object name E?

Comment: I don't understand the question. That is a local variable to the function. `e` has no meaning outside the function and it is not a "name" that is given to the runtime environment

Comment: Thankyou I am new and self learning so I appreciate that explanation